# MP4 to DASH using ffmpeg linux too slow

Tags: c, linux, ffmpeg

Currently, I'm working at a project that contains 2000 video mp4 files, and I need convert all of them in mpeg dash files.

I have this script:

```
MYDIR=$(dirname $(readlink -f ${BASH_SOURCE[0]}))
SAVEDIR=$(pwd)

# Check programs
if [ -z "$(which ffmpeg)" ]; then
    echo "Error: ffmpeg is not installed"
    exit 1
fi

if [ -z "$(which MP4Box)" ]; then
    echo "Error: MP4Box is not installed"
    exit 1
fi

cd "$MYDIR"

TARGET_FILES=$(find ./ -maxdepth 1 -type f \( -name "*.mov" -or -name "*.mp4" \))
for f in $TARGET_FILES
do
  fe=$(basename "$f") # fullname of the file
  f="${fe%.*}" # name without extension

  if [ ! -d "${f}" ]; then #if directory does not exist, convert
    echo "Converting \"$f\" to multi-bitrate video in MPEG-DASH"

    mkdir "${f}"

    ffmpeg -y -i "${fe}" -c:a aac -b:a 192k -vn "${f}_audio.m4a"


    ffmpeg -y -i "${fe}" -preset slow -tune film -vsync passthrough -write_tmcd 0 -an -c:v libx264 -x264opts 'keyint=25:min-keyint=25:no-scenecut' -crf 23 -maxrate 800k -bufsize 2000k -pix_fmt yuv420p -vf "scale=-2:720" -f mp4  "${f}_800.mp4"
    # static file for ios and old browsers and mobile safari
    ffmpeg -y -i "${fe}" -preset slow -tune film -movflags +faststart -vsync passthrough -write_tmcd 0 -c:a aac -b:a 160k -c:v libx264  -crf 23 -maxrate 1400 -bufsize 3000k -pix_fmt yuv420p -f mp4 "${f}/${f}.mp4"


    rm -f ffmpeg*log*
    # if audio stream does not exist, ignore it
    if [ -e "${f}_audio.m4a" ]; then
        MP4Box -dash-strict 2000 -rap -frag-rap  -bs-switching no -profile "dashavc264:live" "${f}_5000.mp4" "${f}_3000.mp4" "${f}_1500.mp4" "${f}_800.mp4" "${f}_400.mp4" "${f}_audio.m4a" -out "${f}/${f}.mpd"
        rm "${f}_5000.mp4" "${f}_3000.mp4" "${f}_1500.mp4" "${f}_800.mp4" "${f}_400.mp4" "${f}_audio.m4a"
    else
        MP4Box -dash-strict 2000 -rap -frag-rap  -bs-switching no -profile "dashavc264:live" "${f}_5000.mp4" "${f}_3000.mp4" "${f}_1500.mp4" "${f}_800.mp4" "${f}_400.mp4" -out "${f}/${f}.mpd"
        rm "${f}_5000.mp4" "${f}_3000.mp4" "${f}_1500.mp4" "${f}_800.mp4" "${f}_400.mp4" 
    fi
    # create a jpg for poster. Use imagemagick or just save the frame directly from ffmpeg is you don't have cjpeg installed.
    ffmpeg -i "${fe}" -ss 00:00:00 -vframes 1  -qscale:v 10 -n -f image2 - | cjpeg -progressive -quality 75 -outfile "${f}"/"${f}".jpg

    fi

done

cd "$SAVEDIR"
```

This is working fine, but, taking a long time to convert only single file, I have intel 7 and a simple mp4 file take 30 min to be converted. How can I accelerate this process? Must I change something in this script?

Thank you.

Comment: Use a faster `-preset`. Can't really suggest anything else without seeing the full log from one of the `ffmpeg` commands (assuming `ffmpeg` is the slow command in the script). You forgot the `k` in one of your `-maxrate`.

Comment: Is really necessary use ffmpeg to reencode the video? Can't I just go ahead with MP4Box instead of reencoding everything?

Answer (score 0):

use the -preset **ultrafast** is better than slow .And more than 400% fast than slow preset

-preset type given below
**ultrafast,
superfast,
veryfast,
faster,
fast,
medium,
slow,
slower,

veryslow**